# Как заменить строку в List<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, словари

Есть у меня словарь, в котором хранятся слова, которые надо заменять из входной строки. На данный момент есть такой код

```
var str = "кадастровый номер 234";
var args = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
args.Add("кадастровый номер", "к/н");

var newstr = args.Aggregate(str, (current, value) =>
       current.Replace(value.Key, value.Value));//к/н 234
```

Так как словарь не позволяет добавлять несколько одинаковых ключей было решено использовать `KeyValuePair`. Как сделать тоже самое для него?

Comment: а зачем вам одинаковые ключи?

Comment: и почему List<KeyValuePair>, а не Dctionary<string, List<string>>

Comment: для чего вам понадобились одинаковые ключи в словаре?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, зачем вы используете `KeyValuePair` ведь этот тип бесполезен без словаря. С тем же успехом можно использовать какой-нибудь Tuple.

Теперь по вопросу:
Никак, так как это структура. Если только удалить старое значение из коллекции и добавить измененное.